# Spring SAML 2.0 with Dynamic relying registration, doesn't work on Reverse Proxy Nginx

Tags: spring-mvc, nginx, tomcat, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've been looking for a solution in many questions and forums but nothing worked for me.
I've a use case, in which we register Idp configuration in another service, and then we retrieve that particular configuration providing an `orgId` query param. Somehow I could built something that works on localhost with Okta as Idp, based on these sites:

Here I could delegate Idp selection before real saml auth gets triggered: 
[Spring Security SAML2 dynamic selection of IDPs or dynamic URLs for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626358/spring-security-saml2-dynamic-selection-of-idps-or-dynamic-urls-for-them)

It works on localhost even SLO, but when we deploy the service to a EKR cluster, for all backend services, at first we can load the login redirection like:

`http://dev.org.com/services/sso/auth-sso?orgId=<id>`

It goes to Okta, and we can login, when it tries to redirect back to our service, the "/" path doesn't get triggered and somehow the url it's redirected to

`http://dev.org.com/auth-sso?error`

We have tried, `context-path` setting in `application.yml` with no success, and lastly I read this reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html#configuration-load-balancing

Also referenced to this questions:
[Spring SAML 2.0 behind Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710112/spring-saml-2-0-behind-nginx)

but this spring saml version, doesn't recognize `SAMLContextProviderLB` or `SAMLContextProviderImpl`

Here some code:

`build.gradle.kt`:

```kotlin
   constraints {
      implementation("org.opensaml:opensaml-core:4.1.1")
      implementation("org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:4.1.1")
      implementation("org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:4.1.1")
   }

   // spring
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

   // saml2
   implementation("org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:2.0.0.M31")
   implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider:5.7.4")
```

In my SamlConfig class, I define these beans:

`securityFilterChain`:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun securityWebFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    
    http
        .authorizeRequests {
            it
            .mvcMatchers("/auth-sso").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers("/actuator/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
        .saml2Login {
            it.loginPage("/auth-sso")
        }
        .saml2Logout{}

    return http.build()
}
```

and a custom implementation of `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository`, as  `LazyRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository`
:

```kotlin
@Bean
protected fun relyingPartyRegistrations(): RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository? {
    return LazyRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository()
}
```

And this is my `/auth-sso`

```kotlin
@GetMapping(value = ["/auth-sso"])
@ResponseBody
fun login(
    @RequestParam(name = "orgId", required = true) orgId: String,
    request: HttpServletRequest,
    response: HttpServletResponse
)  {

    try {

        val id = runBlocking {
            findIdpConfigurationUseCase.execute(object : UserOrganizationLogin {
                override val organizationId = organizationId
                override val token: String? = null
            })
        }

        val spInitiateUrl = "saml2/authenticate/$id"
        log.debug("Redirecting to {}", spInitiateUrl)

        response.sendRedirect(spInitiateUrl)

    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        log.error("Error preparing assertion info: {}", e)
        response.sendRedirect(MessageFormat.format(environment.getRequiredProperty(HOME_URL), ""))
    }
}
```

My "auth entry point" `/` which recieves the Principal crendentials and login the user calling a use case with internally create user and generates token:

```kotlin
@RequestMapping("/")
fun index(model: Model, @AuthenticationPrincipal principal: Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal, response: HttpServletResponse) {

    log.debug("User is authenticated!!!")

    val loginInfo = runBlocking {
        loginUserUseCase.execute(principal)
    }

    response.sendRedirect(
        environment.getRequiredProperty(HOME_URL) +
        MessageFormat.format(environment.getRequiredProperty(SSO_HOME_PARAMS), loginInfo.token, loginInfo.organizationId)
    )
}
```